# Is there a way to isolate an application from environment variables for testing code?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, sandbox

I am developing an application on Windows that makes use of `DLL` files available in the system `PATH` variable. Those `DLL`s are in my my `PATH` for  my development environment. However the application itself is portable that ships with its own dependencies. Is there a way to obscure environment variables from an application/process so I can test my code for portability without having to modify global variables?

Comment: You could create another user for testing purposes, login into the other account and try if that works. Another more complete solution would be to create a virtual machine with a new windows installation and test there everything

Comment: Use one of Microsoft's free Windows VMs

Comment: probably the best solution is mocking, provided your dev environment is appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a bat/cmd file and override PATH then lunch your application from the same bat/cmd file

```
@echo off

Path=C:\TestPath

REM test it that is was overridden 
echo %Path%

REM Lunch your app below
c:\path\to\your\app.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer was helpful. I converted that into a PowerShell function that I can add to my `$profile` so it is always available:

```
function sandbox {
    Write-Output "$args"
    $tempPATH = $env:PATH
    $env:PATH = ""
    if ("$args"[0] -eq '"') { iex "& $args" }
    else { iex "$args" }
    $env:PATH = $tempPATH
}
```

So now, whenever I call `sandbox SOME_COMMAND`, the function empties `PATH`, runs the command, and restores the variable back again.